# Addable table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, material-ui

I am trying to make a table in React, which can add and delete rows. When the user adds data to the rows, I save it (in-state maybe) and work with it.

So it has to have logic like this

[image]

I've tried to do it by myself but seems I don't have enough knowledge for that. Searched like half of the Internet, but didn`t find what I need. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ES6 map for the table.
`state = { dataMap: new Map().set(0, { name: null }), }`

(key = 0, 1, 2, 3 ..., value = {name: "xxx", gmail: "xxx@xxx", phone: "xxx"})

When pressing add row, dataMap add a key. For example:

```
addRow = () => {
        this.setState({ dataMap: this.state.dataMap.set(Math.max(...this.state.dataMap.keys()) + 1, {}) })
}
```

And the table is constructed by this dataMap's value
`[...this.state.dataMap.values()]`

Let me know if I get something wrong. Thank you~